# Exception in thread main java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java

I was implementing a simple HashMap program which stores name and age of persons.
here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

class StoreName {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            String name = sc.nextLine();
            int age = sc.nextInt();
            map.put(name, age);
        }

        for (String key : map.keySet())
            System.out.println(key + "=" + map.get(key));
    }
}
```

when I take input from nextInt() the Scanner throws `InputMismatchException` Exception 
but if I take input from nextLine() and then parse it into int then my code runs properly.Please explain me.

and why should I use nextInt() or nextDouble() anyway if I could parse string input into any type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scanner issue when using nextLine after nextXXX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx)

Answer (score 6):

`sc.nextInt()` doesn't read the entire line.

Suppose you enter

```
John
20
Dan
24
```

Now let's see what each Scanner call will return :

```
  String name=sc.nextLine(); // "John"
  int age=sc.nextInt(); // 20
  String name=sc.nextLine(); // "" (the end of the second line)
  int age=sc.nextInt(); // "Dan" - oops, this is not a number - InputMismatchException
```

The following small change will get over that exception :

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
   String name=sc.nextLine();
   int age=sc.nextInt();
   sc.nextLine(); // add this
   map.put(name,age);
}
```

Now, Scanner will behave properly :

```
String name=sc.nextLine(); // "John"
int age=sc.nextInt(); // 20
sc.nextLine(); // "" (the end of the second line)
String name=sc.nextLine(); // "Dan"
int age=sc.nextInt(); // 24
sc.nextLine(); // "" (the end of the fourth line)
```

Comment: I have one more question.Is there any specific benefit of using nextInt() over parsing the string input into integer type?Please explain.

Comment: @prak I don't see any benefit in using nextInt. Internally it is calling `Integer.parseInt` and throws InputMismatchException when it catches a NumberFormatException. I prefer to do parse the String inputs myself.

Answer (score 1):

Try using sc.next() for reading name instead of using nextLine()

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    String name = sc.next();//Change here
    int age = sc.nextInt();
    map.put(name, age);
}
```

A detailed explanation on the difference between next() and nextLine() can be found here 
[What's the difference between next() and nextLine() methods from Scanner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class)