# Swap the word in the String

Tags: java, swap

```
input:-
1
Ans kot

Output:-
kot Ans
```

**INPUT :** 
the first line of the input contains the number of test cases. Each test case consists of a single line containing the string.

**OUTPUT :**
output the string with the words swapped as stated above.**

Code:-

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = sc.nextInt();
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    String b = sc.next();
    String my[] = b.split(" ");
    StringBuffer r = new StringBuffer();
    for (int j = my.length - 1; j > 0; j--) {
        r.append(my[j] + " ");
    }
    r.append(my[0] + "\n");
    result.append(r.toString());
}
System.out.println(result.toString());
}
```

**What is wrong in my code ? above is code which i am trying.**

Comment: And what's the output of your code?

Comment: i mention above in question @eyp... just reverse the word

Comment: No, that's what you want. I mean what your program does.

Comment: You can design a function which reverse *a single word*; lets call it ```reverser(String):String``` then call it for every word.

Comment: It seams the code of a question in HackerRank... isn't it?

Comment: You're not trying to reverse a word, but a sequence of words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple things:

1. You are using `next` api which will just read your string that you type word by word and you loop until a i.e. in your example just once. So instead use `nextLine` api which will read whole line instead of just a word and then split by space:

   ```
   String b = sc.nextLine();
   ```
2. You are reading input with `nextInt` api followed by enter, you you might sometime end up having return character when reading next token using `next` api. Instead use:

   ```
   int a = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
   ```
3. You are using StringBuffer which has an overhead of obtaining mutex and hence should use StringBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

```
String my[] = b.split(" ");
StringBuffer r = new StringBuffer();
for (int j = my.length - 1; j > 0; j--) {
    r.append(my[j] + " ");
}
```

this snippet of your code is only gonna reverse the sentence "word by word" not "character by character". therefore, you need reverse the string (`my[j]`) before you append it into the `StringBuffer`

Comment: @kucing-terbang any specific reason you have used `StringBuffer` instead of `StringBuilder` ?

Comment: @Ramswaroop No reason, I just copy pasted from the OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int a = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                String b = sc.nextLine();
                String my[] = b.split(" ");
                StringBuffer r = new StringBuffer();
                for (int j = my.length - 1; j > 0; j--) {
                    r.append(my[j] + " ");

                }
                r.append(my[0] + "\n");
                result.append(r.toString());
            }
            System.out.println(result.toString());
        }
```

Comment: But why with next it is not working... and nextLine it is working... can u explain it

Comment: Using next() will only return what comes before a space. nextLine() automatically moves the scanner down after returning the current line.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class

Answer (score 0):

Takes `String` input and return `String` in reverse order of each characters.

```
String reverse(String x) {
        int i = x.length() - 1;
        StringBuilder y = new StringBuilder();
        while (i >= 0) {
            y.append(x.charAt(i));
            i--;
        }

        return y.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String reverseWords(String input) {
    Deque<String> words = new ArrayDeque<>();
    for (String word: input.split(" ")) {
        if (!word.isEmpty()) {
            words.addFirst(word);
        }
    }
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    while (!words.isEmpty()) {
        result.append(words.removeFirst());
        if (!words.isEmpty()) {
            result.append(" ");
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run this code:

```
String[] splitted = yourString.split(" ");

for (int i = splitted.length-1; i>=0; i--){
    System.out.println(splitted[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
Code:-
               
    Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
        int a =Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        StringBuffer result= new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i <a; i++) {
     String b=sc.nextLine();
        String my[]= b.split(" ");
        StringBuffer r = new StringBuffer();
     for (int j = my.length-1; j >0; j--) {
      r.append(my[j]+" ");
      
     }
     r.append(my[0] + "\n");
          result.append(r.toString());
    }
     System.out.println(result.toString());
   

enter code here
```