# Using string in switch statement, by taking input from user

Tags: java, string, switch-statement, incompatibletypeerror

In the below code, during compilation, i get 'incompatible types' error.
If I user other logic, like charAt(0) and all, this works fine.
Isn't there any way to use string in a java switch statement?
I'm using JDK 7.

Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class cCode
{
    public static void Main(String args [])`
    {
        System.out.println("Enter country code\nChoices: IND, USA, JPN, NZ, WI");
        Scanner cc = new Scanner(System.in);
        switch(cc)
        {
            case "IND":
                System.out.println(cc+" refers to INDIA");
                break;  
            case "USA":
                System.out.println(cc+" refers to UNITED STATES");
                break;
            case "JPN":
                System.out.println(cc+" refers to JAPAN");
                break;
            case "NZ":
                System.out.println(cc+" refers to NEW ZEALAND");
                break;
            case "WI":
                System.out.println(cc+" refers to WEST INDIES");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid choice");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: cc is an object of scanner type, and you are comparing it with strings.

Comment: Try adding `String text = cc.nextLine();` after `Scanner cc = new Scanner(System.in);`, and then use 'text' for your switch.

Comment: ps: if you use significant variable names, your error would be clearer. IE: Scanner inputScanner...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I switch on a String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/why-cant-i-switch-on-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code by taking input from user.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class cCode {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    System.out.println("Enter country code\nChoices: IND, USA, JPN, NZ, WI");
    Scanner cc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String txt = cc.nextLine();
    switch (txt) {
        case "IND":
            System.out.println(txt + " refers to INDIA");
            break;

        case "USA":
            System.out.println(txt + " refers to UNITED STATES");
            break;

        case "JPN":
            System.out.println(txt + " refers to JAPAN");
            break;

        case "NZ":
            System.out.println(txt + " refers to NEW ZEALAND");
            break;

        case "WI":
            System.out.println(txt + " refers to WEST INDIES");
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid choice");
   }
}}
```

Comment: You can see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do this:

```
String theText = cc.next();
switch(theText) {
   //your code.
}
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I suspect the OP needs to put in a variable as he/she prints it later.

Comment: I also am getting this error:

java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=4][match valid=true][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\,][decimal separator=\.][positive prefix=][negati
ve prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q?\E][infinity string=\Q∞\E] refers to NEW ZEALAND

Comment: Fixed it. that was due to cc at SoP.