# Simple Calculator Gone Wrong in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to teach my friend Java. I tried this simple calculator.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean powerOn = true;

    while(powerOn) {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to the calculator\nPlease enter a number (Enter 3.14 for PI)"); 
        double firstNumber = userInput.nextDouble();

        if(firstNumber == 3.14) firstNumber = Math.PI;

        System.out.println("Please enter an operation(+,-,*,/, Square Root)");
        String operation = userInput.next();

        if(operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Square Root")) System.out.println(Math.sqrt(firstNumber));

        else {
            System.out.println("Please enter another number");
            double secondNumber = userInput.nextDouble();

            if(secondNumber == 3.14) secondNumber = Math.PI;

            if (operation.equals("+")) {
                if(firstNumber == 9 && secondNumber == 10) System.out.println("21");
                else System.out.println(firstNumber+secondNumber); 
            }
            else if (operation.equals("-")) System.out.println(firstNumber-secondNumber);
            else if (operation.equals("*")) System.out.println(firstNumber*secondNumber);
            else if (operation.equals("/")) System.out.println(firstNumber/secondNumber);
        }

        System.out.println("Power off?");
        String off = userInput.next();

        if(off.contains("y")) System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

If you do square root, it prints enter another number and then throws an exception... I know what's happening, but why and how do I prevent it?

And just a side note can someone explain to me the difference between `Scanner#next()` and `Scanner#nextLine`?

Comment: For the second part of your query --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class

Comment: Add your exception with full stack trace to your question.

Comment: plus 1 for Balwinder's comment

Answer (score 0):

next() returns the string before the space while nextLine() as you might have guessed returns the whole line .

You are probably also getting the error because of the same reason as your string "Square Root" has a space and hence operation variable always have "Sqaure" value assigned to it rather than "Square Root".

This pushes it to the else block instead of if.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the following code

```
String operation = userInput.next();
```

with following

```
String operation = userInput.nextLine();
```

The reason being the `next()` will only return what comes before a space. `nextLine()` automatically moves the scanner down after returning the current line.

In your current code, when you try to get the square root, the `operation` will just store "Square" instead of "Square Root" and therefore the following if condition isn't satisfied

```
if(operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Square Root"))
```

and the code goes into `else` condition and asks for another number and tries to process it and in the else block it throws error on this line

```
double secondNumber = userInput.nextDouble();
```

Apart from changing the `next()` to  `nextLine()` in your code, you need to update following

```
double firstNumber = userInput.nextDouble();
```

with

```
double firstNumber = userInput.nextDouble();    
userInput.nextLine();
```

to ensure that the scanner doesn't skip your `nextLine()` because in `nextDouble()` method only the double is consumed and the next line characters (\n) aren't.

Similarly update

```
double secondNumber = userInput.nextDouble();
```

with

```
double secondNumber = userInput.nextDouble();
userInput.nextLine();
```

For more info about skipping of `nextLine()` method while using `nextDouble()` [refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods).

Answer (score 0):

To fix your issue add a `scan.nextLine();`
Before you scan in the operation. And while scanning in the operation use a `scan.nextLine();` as well instead of the `scan.next();`

Think of the scan as the location of the cursor. A `scan.nextDouble();` will place the cursor after the last digit of the number, and a `scan.nextLine();` will scan in what ever is inbetween the cursor's location and the beginning of the next line. `scan.next();` won't scan in the entire line.