# Java Scanner Class delimiter usage - How to adjust

Tags: java, string, delimiter

Using Scanner class to write a console program that takes user input of name, address etc as a String using sc.next().

However when I enter more than one word separated by spaces (e.g "123 Main Street") it jumps ahead and enters the separate words as separate strings into the next variables one by one.

```
System.out.println("Please enter forename: ");
    String fName = sc.next();
    System.out.println("Please enter surname: ");
    String sName = sc.next();
    System.out.println("Please enter your street address:");
    String street = sc.next();
    System.out.println("Please enter your city: ");
    String city = sc.next();
    System.out.println("Please enter your postcode: ");
    String postcode = sc.next();
```

This outputs:

```
Please enter forename: 
John
Please enter surname: 
Smith
Please enter your street address:
123 Main Street
Please enter your city: 
Please enter your postcode:
```

I'm sure this has something to do with how the Scanner uses delmiters, the spaces are used to break the string entered into separate string but I don't know how to fix it.... Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `Scaner#nextLine`...

Comment: Related: [What's the difference between next() and nextLine() methods from Scanner class?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22458575/1065197)