# Java: How to deal with string index out of range error?

Tags: java, string

I'm new to Java and I can't figure out how to solve this problem:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1

Here's the entire code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create a Scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Step 1:  Ask user to enter first and last name
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter your first and last name: ");
    String name = input.nextLine();
    String major = "";
    String classification = "";

    //Step 2: Ask user to enter two characters
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter two characters (1st character represents   the major and 2nd character represents the classification): ");
    char ch = input.next().charAt(0);
    char ch1 = input.nextLine().charAt(1);

    //Step 3:  Print statement 
    switch(ch) {
        case 'i': major = "Information Technology"; break;
        case 'c': major = "Computer Science"; break; 
        case 'm': major = "Mathematics"; break;
        case 'p': major = "Physics"; break;    
        case 'b': major = "Biology"; break;
        case 'e': major = "Engineering"; break;
        case 'h': major = "History"; break; 
        case 'j': major = "Journalism"; break;
        case 'a': major = "Art and Design"; break;
        case 'l': major = "Literature"; break;
        case 's': major = "Sport Medicine"; break;
        default: System.out.println("\nInvalid Major Code");
            System.out.println("Please enter a character followed by an integer!");
        break;
    }//end of switch

    //Step 3:  Print statement 
    switch(ch1) {
        case '1': classification = "Freshman"; break;
        case '2': classification = "Sophmore"; break;
        case '3': classification = "Junior"; break;
        case '4': classification = "Senior"; break;    
        case '5': classification = "Graduate"; break;
        default: System.out.println("\nInvalid Classification Code");
            System.out.println("Please enter a character followed by an integer!");
            break;
    }//end of switch

    System.out.println("\nMajor and classification is: " + major + "" + classification);
    System.out.println("\nThank You!");
}//end of main
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you put the stack trace for the error you got?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `char ch = input.next().charAt(0);` will read **both the characters**, but not "consume" the newline character that is generated when the user hits Enter.

You then call `input.nextLine()`, which **will** consume the newline character (but now the two characters were already consumed by `next()`, so the resulting string is empty). Calling `.charAt(1)` on the empty string generates the exception because there is no position `(1)` in the empty string (it's length is 0).

Instead I'd suggest you use something like this:

```
//Step 2: Ask user to enter two characters
System.out.println("\nPlease enter two characters (1st character represents   the major and 2nd character represents the classification): ");

String majorAndClassification = "";
while( majorAndClassification.length() != 2 )
    majorAndClassification = input.nextLine();

char ch = majorAndClassification.charAt(0);
char ch1 = majorAndClassification.charAt(1);
```

This will make sure that the user enters two characters - if he doesn't, he'll have to try again until he does. A slightly better option would of course be to print out the prompt every time, like so:

```
//Step 2: Ask user to enter two characters  
String majorAndClassification = "";
while( majorAndClassification.length() != 2 ){
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter two characters (1st character represents   the major and 2nd character represents the classification): ");
    majorAndClassification = input.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you enter the second entered character, it reads out of range because of `charAt(1)`. Just change it to `charAt(0)`, because you alwayws read only the first character of the input:

```
char ch = input.next().charAt(0);
char ch1 = input.next().charAt(0);
```

It works for both inputs:

```
i
3
```

And also `i 3`

Answer (score 1):

Calling

```
final char ch1 = input.nextLine().charAt(1);
```

expects a whole line to be read, and there getting the second letter.
But

```
char ch = input.next().charAt(0);
```

already consumed the first char.

So you should read the whole input in one go, then (do more checking and then) get your chars.

```
//Step 2: Ask user to enter two characters
System.out.println("\nPlease enter two characters (1st character represents   the major and 2nd character represents the classification): ");
final String reply = input.nextLine();
final char ch = reply.charAt(0);
final char ch1 = reply.charAt(1);


//Step 3:  Print statement
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your code so that it first checks for the length of the input before it refer to the index of the String. Something like the following:

```
 //Step 2: Ask user to enter two characters
System.out.println("\nPlease enter two characters (1st character represents   the major and 2nd character represents the classification): ");
String inputNext = input.next();
String inputNextLine;
if(inputNext.length>0 && inputNextLine.length>0){
char ch = inputNext;
char ch1 = inputNextLine;


//Step 3:  Print statement 
switch(ch) 
{
    case 'i': major = "Information Technology";
    break;
    case 'c': major = "Computer Science";
    break;
    case 'm': major = "Mathematics";
    break;
    case 'p': major = "Physics";
    break;    
    case 'b': major = "Biology";
    break;
    case 'e': major = "Engineering";
    break;
    case 'h': major = "History";
    break; 
    case 'j': major = "Journalism";
    break;
    case 'a': major = "Art and Design";
    break;
    case 'l': major = "Literature";
    break;
    case 's': major = "Sport Medicine";
    break;

    default: System.out.println("\nInvalid Major Code");
    System.out.println("Please enter a character followed by an integer!");
    break;

}//end of switch

//Step 3:  Print statement 
switch(ch1)
{
    case '1': classification = "Freshman";
    break;
    case '2': classification = "Sophmore";
    break;
    case '3': classification = "Junior";
    break;
    case '4': classification = "Senior";
    break;    
    case '5': classification = "Graduate";
    break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change your code from `char ch1 = input.nextLine().charAt(1);` 
to this `char ch1 = input.next().charAt(0);`

you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class) for more details about differences between next() and nextLine()