# Formal Greeting app only displays last if statement can't figure out why

Tags: java, eclipse

```
package chapter6;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class formal_greeting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String title;
        String name;
        String mr = null;
        String miss = null;
        String ms = null;
        String mrs = null;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        name = input.next();
        System.out.print("Enter your title: ");
        title = input.next();

        if (title.equalsIgnoreCase(mr)) {
             System.out.println("Hello sir");
             }else if (title.equalsIgnoreCase(miss)) {
             System.out.println("Hello ma'am");
             }else if (title.equalsIgnoreCase(ms)) {
             System.out.println("Hello ma'am");
             }else if (title.equalsIgnoreCase(mrs)) {
             System.out.println("Hello ma'am");
             }else {
             System.out.println("Hello " + name);
             }



    }

}
```

I can't figure out why my if statements won't work. so far it only displays (Hello "name") can someone please tell me what is wrong with my if statement???

Comment: I'm surprised this code even _compiles_; it should not because you are missing a closing parenthesis around the class.

Comment: All the variables(mr, miss, ms, mrs) you're checking in if condition are set to null. And in title variable you might have actual values like 'Mr', 'Miss', 'Ms', 'Mrs'.

Comment: Initialize all you variables

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not in the if statements.Change your method `input.next()` to `input.nextLine()` .Because using `next()` you will get only what you entered before the space. But if you use `nextLine()` the Scanner will read the entire input line.
For more reference [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class) here.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the difference between a String variable and a string literal.

In your code, `mr` is a string variable. The value that it stores is `null` as you can see from this line:

```
String mr = null;
```

In the if statement, you test whether the user input is equal to the value string variable. Let's say you entered "Mr" in the console:

```
User input    Value of the mr variable
"Mr"          null
```

Are they the same? No.

The same goes for all the if statements. Finally the execution comes to the `else` and executes the stuff there since every if statement failed.

What you need to do is to use a string literal instead of a string variable.

A string literal is denoted by double quotes:

```
"This is a string literal"
```

So your if statements would look like:

```
if (title.equalsIgnoreCase("mr")) {
/*                         ⬆︎ ⬆︎
                          Quotes here!
*/
```

Alternatively, you can use variables as well. But you should not give them a value of `null`. Instead, give them a string literal:

```
String mr = "mr";
// etc.
```

This way, you don't need to change your if statement.