# Class java - array of class, receiving data from the user

Tags: java, class

I'm trying to put values into an array of type holiday but i get error 
when i put the values When the index i becomes 1 (in the for loop).

Is this the correct way to receive the values into the constructor?

The error i get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at ExamQ1.main.main(main.java:13)
```

The main:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    Holiday[] h = new Holiday[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < h.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        h[i] = new Holiday(in.nextLine(), in.nextLine(), in.nextInt());
    }
}
}
```

The class:

```
public class Holiday {
private String name;
private String hebrewMonth;

private int vacationDays;

public Holiday(String name, String hebrewMonth, int vacationDays) {
    this.name = name;
    this.hebrewMonth = hebrewMonth;
    this.setVacationDays(vacationDays);
}

public void setName(String name) {

    this.name = name;
}
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}
public void sethebrewMonth(String hebrewMonth) {
    this.hebrewMonth = hebrewMonth;
}
public String getHebrewMonth() {
    return this.hebrewMonth;
}

public void setVacationDays(int vacationDays) {
    this.vacationDays = vacationDays;
}

public int getVacationDays() {
    return this.vacationDays;
}

public String toString() {
    String str = "name: " + this.name + ",hebrew Month: "
            + this.hebrewMonth + ",vaction days: " + this.vacationDays;
    return str;
}
}
```

thank's

Comment: What are you giving as input?

Comment: aaa>>>>
bbb>>>>
1>>>>
ccc>>>>
vvv   ---->>>> here the error start

Comment: This is not a good way of inserting elements, your scanner might not even return any results so you should wrap things around before doing anything with them like so: while (in.hasNext()) {}

Comment: i too had the same problem ...Read this-[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods)

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to use `next()` after having used `nextInt()` to consume the rest of the unread characters.

```
for (int i = 0; i < h.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
    h[i] = new Holiday(in.nextLine(), in.nextLine(), in.nextInt());
    in.next();
}
```

---

Here is your entry

```
aaa bbb 1 ccc vvv
```

If you don't use `in.next()`, this is what will happen :

```
LOOP 1 :

in.nextLine()    ->    aaa
in.nextLine()    ->    bbb
in.nextInt()     ->    1

//This looks OK.

LOOP 2 :

in.nextLine()    ->    **UNREAD CHARACTER LEFT AFTER in.nextInt()**
in.nextLine()    ->    ccc
in.nextInt()     ->    vvv **INPUT MISMATCH BECAUSE IT IS NOT AN INT**
```

Comment: but i press Enter after each entry

Comment: @liran The problem is that you were not using `in.next()` after `nextInt()`

Comment: for what the: in.next(); in the for?

Comment: @liran to consume the rest of the unread characters after `nextInt()`

Comment: i write in for : if (i < h.length - 1)
    in.next();      Because he asked me again at the end of the loop type value and I do not want it, this is ok?

Comment: i write  in.next(); instead of  in.nextLine();   but why the int No need to change to  in.next();?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods

Comment: this may help you @liran

Answer (score 1):

Just use `in.next()` instead of `in.nextLine()`.
Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class) to see the difference.