# String concat error using Scanner class?

Tags: java, string

I have a error when i give a input for `string  t= "is my favorite language"`; 
it shows output `java is` . please tell what i made a mistake.

```
public class DataTypes {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            String s = "Java ";

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            String t = scan.next();

           String u = s.concat(t);
            System.out.println(u);
    }
    }
```

Comment: use `scan.nextLine()`

Comment: See [What's the difference between next() and nextLine() methods from Scanner class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class).

Comment: You're here long enough to know that you're not allowed to change your question to something else, if there is already at least one answer about your original question. So I rolled your last edit back. If you have a new issue, then create a new question.

Comment: @ Tom,but someone will be tell it's already asked question?

Answer (score 0):

`scan.next()` will get the next token from the input. The default delimiter for this is whitespace, so it will get the first word from your input.

To get all of the input up until the newline (when the user presses enter) use `scan.nextLine()` instead.

```
String s = "Java ";
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

String t = scan.nextLine();

String u = s + t;
System.out.println(u);
```

Comment: i edited my question but it did not print that statement in the following order of execution

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
scanner.nextLine()
```

This will read a whole line till the system defined line seperator (usually \n)

scanner.next() only reads the next token till space.