# Spliting A String Type and put Into a new array in a Loop

Tags: java, file, io, readfile

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class gTextFile {

    static LinkedList<gText> list = new LinkedList<gText>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scnOne = new Scanner(System.in);

        String eCode;

        System.out.print("Employee Code: ");
        eCode = scnOne.nextLine();

        readFile();
        gEmpName("eCode");
    }

    public static void readFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File nFile = new File("C:\\JAVAP\\GetTextFile\\employee.txt");
        Scanner scnTwo = new Scanner(nFile);
        String oTemp;
            while(scnTwo.hasNext()) {
            oTemp = scnTwo.next();
            String EmCode[] = oTemp.split(" ");
            String Name[] = EmCode[1].split(",");
            String idCode = EmCode[0];
            String lastname = Name[0];
            String firstname = Name[1];
            //System.out.println("FName " + firstname);
            //System.out.println("LName " + lastname);
            gText gT = new gText(firstname, lastname, idCode);
            list.add(gT);
            }
        scnTwo.close();
    }

    public static void gEmpName(String EmpCode) {
        Iterator<gText> itr = list.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            gText gT = itr.next();
            if(gT.id.equals(EmpCode)){
                System.out.println("Employee Name: " + gT.Fname + " " + gT.Lname);
            }

        }

    }

}

public class gText {
String Fname;
String Lname;
String id;

    gText(String First, String Last, String ID) {
        this.Fname = First;
        this.Lname = Last;
        this.id = ID;

    }

    public String gFName() {
        return Fname;
    }

    public String gLName() {
        return Lname;
    }

    public String gId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

[image: TextFile]

What are the problem in my code?? the specific code doesn't show out when I run my program. It always say that there are problem. This always come out in the console, when I put the Employee Code.
     Employee Code: A11-0001
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at gTextFile.readFile(gTextFile.java:28)
        at gTextFile.main(gTextFile.java:17)

Comment: for start I think you want `gEmpName(eCode); // the variable`

Comment: Also check for blank lines in your text file

Comment: Take a debugger (aka Eclipse) and set a breakpoint at the line where you get the exception. Look at the values of `oTemp ` and `EmCode` and you know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `oTemp = scnTwo.nextLine();` instead of `oTemp = scnTwo.next();` in your `readFile()` method. When using `next()` you are just getting what comes before first space, in your case only employee code, so use `nextLine()` to fetch complete line. For more clarification on difference between `next()` and `nextLine()`, refer below link

[What's the difference between next() and nextLine() methods from Scanner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class)

Also, you may want to use `gEmpName(eCode);` instead of `gEmpName("eCode");`

Following is the code:

```
public class gTextFile {

static LinkedList<gText> list = new LinkedList<gText>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scnOne = new Scanner(System.in);

    String eCode;

    System.out.print("Employee Code: ");
    eCode = scnOne.nextLine();

    readFile();
    gEmpName(eCode);
}

public static void readFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
    File nFile = new File("/home/path/abc.txt");
    Scanner scnTwo = new Scanner(nFile);
    String oTemp;
        while(scnTwo.hasNext()) {
        oTemp = scnTwo.nextLine();
        String EmCode[] = oTemp.split(" ");
        String Name[] = EmCode[1].split(",");
        String idCode = EmCode[0];
        String lastname = Name[0];
        String firstname = Name[1];
        gText gT = new gText(firstname, lastname, idCode);
        list.add(gT);
        }
    scnTwo.close();
}

public static void gEmpName(String EmpCode) {
    Iterator<gText> itr = list.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        gText gT = itr.next();
        if(gT.id.equals(EmpCode)){
            System.out.println("Employee Name: " + gT.Fname + " " + gT.Lname);
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: I tried to use the nextLine() but when I run it, it only put the code to the eCode and and nothing shows out in the console. and when I use next(), there's a problem with the code String Name[] = EmCode[1].split(","); in the readFile() method. this comes out always,Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at gTextFile.readFile(gTextFile.java:28)
 at gTextFile.main(gTextFile.java:17)

Comment: @sethoy updated answer and included the code. Try running it.