# Problems at detecting spacebars at Strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, encryption, spaces

So I'm doing a program that takes a user input and when it finds chars that are similar to numbers, it replaces it by the number. (For example, it replaces O's by 0's, e's by 3's, etc) The problem is that when it finds a blank space it all messes up. You can check by compiling the code that the output is completely messed up.

```
/* Program to encrypt text replacing some letters by similar numbers
Done by: Gabriel Mello
*/
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String input; //Allocating space for user input
    char[] output=new char[100000]; //Allocating space for final output
    while(true){ // Lets it work as many times as wished


     System.out.println("Escribí la frase que quieras transformar"); // Spanish for input your frase
     input=sc.next(); //Takes user input

         for(int i=0; i<=input.length()-1;i++){ //Iterates over every char in the input
                     switch(input.charAt(i)){//Checks wether the current digit is valid for replacement,
                     case 'O':                    // if it is, it replaces it, if not, it leaves it as it is.
                     case 'o': output[i]='0';
                     break;
                     case 'L':
                     case 'l': 
                     case 'I':
                     case 'i': output[i]='1';
                     break;
                     case 'Z':
                     case 'z': output[i]='2';
                     break;
                     case 'E':
                     case 'e': output[i]='3';
                     break;
                     case 'A':
                     case 'a': output[i]='4';
                     break;
                     case 'S':
                     case 's': output[i]='5';
                     break;
                     case 'G':
                     case 'g': output[i]='6';
                     break;
                     case 'T':
                     case 't': output[i]='7';
                     break;
                     case 'B':
                     case 'b': output[i]='8';
                     break;
                     case 'P':
                     case 'p': output[i]='9';
                     break;
                     default: output[i]=input.charAt(i);
                     }

         }

             System.out.println(output); //Prints the output
             for(int i=0;i<=output.length-1;i++){ //Resets the output array
                 output[i]=' ';
             }
    }


}
}
```

Comment: Add sample input and error output in your question

Comment: Your code prints several new lines which makes it difficult to solve the problem. Try moving the `System.out.println(output)` out of your while loop.

Comment: The while loop just lets the user use the program several times without having to run it over and over again. Just ignore it

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with the debugger and inspect what's going on when it hits a space?

Comment: Tried to use Eclipse's debugger, don't know how it works tho, it just appears to run the code the same way

Comment: You wouldn't even get an output(At least, not what you expect). You print your `output` array, which is declared as `char[] output=new char[100000];` This would print all the `100000` elements in the array, even though you might not have filled the entire array. This would result in empty lines printed over the screen. Did you **try running** the code ?

Comment: I obviusly did. If the input were "How are you doing" the output would be "d01n9"

Comment: Can't you just check it the `char` is a space, and if `true` skip to the next `character` ?

Comment: Then there would be no blank spaces, hence the output would look like "h0w4r3y0ud01n9"

Comment: Then just do `output[i] = ' '` , whenever its a space.

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do. The default case triggers when the char ain't replacable and copies it as it was

Comment: Got it, You are inputting just the first word through your keyboard. Try replacing `sc.next()` with `sc.nextLine()`. Tell Me if that fixes the problem

Comment: Oh, I'll try that, even though in some previous versions it did recieve the complete input. Once I finish eating I'll tell you.

Comment: @Otomeram Just so you know, here is a link you might refer [to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class)

Comment: I see, though I insist it read the whole line in previous versions

Comment: @Otomeram Could you possibly give that code you keep referring to ?

Comment: I'll see wether eclipse's history keeps it.

Comment: And one hint: move initializion to top, so before you read the input.

Comment: @Otomeram Did you solve the problem ?

Comment: Just finishing eating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scanner input splits at spaces. So if you type in `12 34` the first input your code sees is `12`. It Runs through the `for(int i=0; i<=input.length()-1;i++)` loop, then the while loop finds another input `34` and again runs through it. See the Java doc:

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

Replace `input=sc.next()` by `input=sc.nextLine()` to fix it.

Comment: What do you mean by `the while loop finds another input "34" and again runs throu it.` ?