# Linear Search Array and String

Tags: java, arrays, string

I've an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` error here but I have no idea where abouts it is. In the code I am creating an array where the user inputs the size. the array is a string and the imputs are then all words. Then the user is asked to search the array for a word and see how many times it is there.

Can anyone help?

```
import java.util.*; 
public class SearchArray {  
    public static void main (String[]args)  {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int row = scan.nextInt();
        int col = scan.nextInt();
        String search = new String();
        String array[][] = new String[row][col];
        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < col; j++){
                array[i][j] = scan.nextLine();
            }
            System.out.println(countStrings(array,search));
        }  
    }   
    public static int countStrings(String[][]array, String search)   {
        int count = 0;
        int row = array.length;
        int col = array[0].length;
        for(int i = 0; i < col; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < row; j++){
                if(array[i][j] == search){
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;   
    } 
}
```

Comment: You've swapped row and col in the last nested loops.

Comment: You shouldn't compare strings by `==`. use `.equal` instead.

Comment: It isnt actually letting me input everything to the array either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all use `scan.next()` instead of `scan.nextLine()`.

```
array[i][j] = scan.next();
```

[see this for difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class)

And String is object and they are always same. So don't compare it using `==`. Use `.equals()` to compare two strings.

```
array[i][j].equals(search);
```

`==`tests for reference equality (whether they are the same object).

`.equals()` tests for value equality (whether they are logically "equal").

And yeah, as mentioned is comments by others, you have swapped rows and columns in last nested `for` loop.

It should be:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++){
            if(array[i][j].equals(search)){
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps :)

EDIT:

Keep this line out of your nested for loops:

```
System.out.println(countStrings(array,search));
```

and also use `array[0].length` to get rows and `array[1].length` to get length of col.

So the whole code will look like:

```
import java.util.*; 
public class SearchArray {  
public static void main (String[] args)  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int row = scan.nextInt();
    int col = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Scan the string to be searched!");
    String search = scan.next();
    String array[][] = new String[row][col];

    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++){
            array[i][j] = scan.next();
        }

    }

    System.out.println(countStrings(array, search));

}   
public static int countStrings(String[][]array, String search)   {
    int count = 0;
    int row = array[0].length;
    int col = array[1].length;
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++){
            if(array[i][j].equals(search)){
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;   
} 
}
```

Comment: Ive only changed these and now whenever i enter n the row and col it doesnt let me finish the array. eg. with a 2x2 array i could only enter 2 words before i got an error. It seems to only allow me to enter as many words as the second digit./

Comment: So if i enter 3 rows and 2 columns, it will only allow 2 words and then i get "java.lang.NullPointerException
 at SearchArray.countStrings(SearchArray.java:33)
 at SearchArray.main(SearchArray.java:18)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:267)"

Comment: Now its entering the array and wont add anything to search. I have moved the line `String search = new String();` to be after i enter it just above where i call the countStrings method.

Comment: where you've scanned `search` string?

Comment: amazing! yes. Youve no idea the headache I have had with this today. Thank you!

Comment: one more thing, how would i make this say duck = Duck? ignoring upper and lower case

Comment: Use this: `s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2)` @Shauna

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i dont have enough reputation points to comment on your follow up. 
The reason you cannot fill the array is probably because the 
`scan.nextInt();` doesn't consume the "\n".

you can consume the newline char by changing your code to consume the \n like so: 
`Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     int row = scan.nextInt();
     int col = scan.nextInt();
     scan.nextLine();`

Comment: Its still giving the same error. Its really frustrating I've been looking over it all day