# Why doesn't the code work?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Formula {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner numIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner form = new Scanner(System.in);

    double r, d, h, a;
    String formula;

    System.out.println("Please state which circle formula you want to use:");
    System.out.println("Circumference");
    System.out.println("Area");
    System.out.println("Cylinder volume");

    formula = form.next();

    switch (formula) {
    case "Circumference":
        System.out.println("Please state the diameter: ");
        d = numIn.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("The circumference is:");
        System.out.println(3.14 * d);
        break;

    case "Area":
        System.out.println("Please state the radius: ");
        r = numIn.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("The area is:");
        System.out.println(3.14 * (r * r));
        break;

    case "Cylinder volume":
        System.out.println("State the area of the base: ");
        a = numIn.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("State the height of the cylinder: ");
        h = numIn.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("the volume is: ");
        System.out.println(a * h);
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println("Option not recognized");
        break;
    }
}

}
```

as you can see I am trying to create a formula calculator (note: I am only a begginer) and it all seemed to be working until the last 'case'. The last case "Cylinder volume" is not recognized when I type it in the console. All other cases work fine, and I do not see a difference between "Cylinder volume" and the other ones. Please help!

Comment: use `form.nextLine()` instead of `form.next()` or you'll only get the first word ("Cylinder").

Comment: *"Why doesn't the code work"* is a bad title. It could apply to probably 90%+ of questions on SO. You might want to be more specific.

Comment: i guess you need to know the [difference between next() and nextLine()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class). And for the future need please [read the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Comment: Pro Tip: Have the user enter just a menu-item number. Nobody wants to type "Cylinder volume". They want to type "3" ...

Answer (score 2):

That is you used

```
 formula = form.next();
```

This only reads until end of the word but not the space
so when you put  "Cylinder volume" it reads Cylinder only.

It will work if you change it to

```
 formula = form.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Zircon has the solution. However, it may also be helpful to print in the default case what `formula` is set to:

```
   default:
        System.out.println("Option: " + formula + " not recognized");
        break;
```

Doing this kind of stuff will help your sanity in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Scanner form = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\n");
```

Remember that Scanner doesn't work with non-ascii character.

Another test could be printing 'formula' *before* the switch, and check its content.