# Using a Scanner, how do I collect all of the input that I enter?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean flag = true;

System.out.print("What is your name? ");
flag = true;
while(flag == true){
    name = input.next();
    fullName = fullName + " " + name;
    if(input.hasNext() == false){
        flag = false;
    }
}
```

The above code is just a sample of my whole program, but this piece of the code is where I am having problems.

With the above code, the input that I enter into the console is `"the one"`. The problem is after `input.next()` collects `"one"` and then adds it to `fullName`, when the code goes to the if statement to check if there is more input (which there is none), the program just hangs. I am using `BlueJ` and the program debugger says that the thread is still running but nothing is going on.  I'm wondering how do I collect the entire input of `"the one"` using a `Scanner`?

Comment: Can you not just put input.hasNext() as you while condition? eg. while(input.hasNext()){

Comment: No. After the last input, once the program goes to check input.hasNext() the final time the program just hangs.  Bluej debugger says that the thread is running, but I can't step forward into the code and their is no error showing up.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use

```
if(!input.hasNext()){
    flag = false;
}
```

Rather than using

```
if(input.hasNext() == false){
    flag = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `name = input.nextLine();`

Refer: [What's the difference between next() and nextLine() methods from Scanner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class)

Java doc [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

> next() Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.
>
> nextLine() Advances this scanner past the current line and returns
>   the input that was skipped.

```
while (true) {
    name = input.nextLine();
    if(name.length() == 0){
        break;
    }
    fullName = fullName + " " + name;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work. When I use nextLine it goes past my input, and just outputs the later statements

Comment: @thankgodforthissite, I have added the modified code for execution.