# How to scan time in hh:mm format as string and get the value of hh and min in integer?

Tags: java, string, parsing

```
String s= sc.nextLine();  //Suppose I take HH:MM (Time) as string... say 09:45
```

So s becomes...

```
s = "09:45";
```

My question is how do I take HH = 09 and MM = 45 as numbers in integer variable in JAVA.

I have tried ...

```
String s1[]= s.split(":");

int HH= Integer.valueof(s1[0]);

int MM= Integer.valueof(s1[1]);
```

But it is giving this exception...

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: ""  at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown
>   Source) at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source) at
>   appstreet.Question1.main(Question1.java:42)

Comment: add the java tag at least

Comment: that should work, i guess you are giving an invalid input

Comment: I am giving input as 09:30 ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (Assuming input format HH:MM):

```
String s = sc.next(); //instead of nextLine()
int hh = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0,2));
int mm = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(3));
```

Or as you did:

```
String s = sc.next(); //instead of nextLine()
String arr[] = s.split(":");
int hh = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
int mm = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class) for difference between `next()` and `nextLine()`.

Answer (score 0):

NumberFormatException means you are trying to convert into an integer something that is not possible to be converter into such...

you have multiple ways to do that anyway:

```
String s = "09:45";
String s1[] = s.split(":");
int HH = Integer.valueOf(s1[0]);
int MM = Integer.valueOf(s1[1]);
System.out.println(HH);
System.out.println(MM);

// another option using java8
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
System.out.println(lt.getHour());
System.out.println(lt.getMinute());
```