# Why can I not let my program run my method over and over (while loop)?

Tags: java

This is a diary program which allows you to write something in your diary (obviously). After typing enter and pressing enter, the page closes and its gonna be safed in a list. My problem is that it only runs once when I have Pages(); in the main method, so I tried this loop. It doesnt work for me and i dont know why. Need some help

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NotizbuchKlasse{
    public static void Pages() {
        System.out.println("day 1 : Write something in your diary.");
        System.out.println("Write enter if you are done writing.");
        ArrayList<String> List = new ArrayList<String>();
        String ListInList;
        Scanner write = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            ListInList = write.next();
            List.add(ListInList);
        } while (! ListInList.equals("enter"));
        List.remove(List.size()-1);
        write.close();          
        System.out.println("This is now your page. Your page is gonna be created after writing something new.");
        System.out.println(List);
    }

    public static void main(String[]Args){
        boolean run = true;
        do{
            Pages();
        } while(run);
    } 
}
```

Error:

```
This is now your page. Your page is gonna be created after writing something 
new.
Exception in thread "main" [hello]
day 1 : Write something in your diary.
Write enter if you are done writing.
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at NotizbuchKlasse.Pages(NotizbuchKlasse.java:12)
    at NotizbuchKlasse.main(NotizbuchKlasse.java:24)
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`write.hasNext()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext--)?

Comment: I am askin why the loop in the main thread does not work for the program

Comment: `write.close();` closes Scanner but also stream which scanner was using so `System.in` which prevents you from reading from it again. So when you are using `next()` it throws NoSuchElementException. It is better to have one scanner for whole application which is handling `System.in`. You can create one in main method and pass it to other methods as argument.

Comment: I suggest that you learn about Java naming conventions. Typically class and interface names start with an uppercase letter and variable names start with a lower case letter. Also, the Java API has an interface named `List`, so this is not a good choice for a variable name. Instead you can use `list`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to check whether there is something to read before you read it. You're not currently, and that's why you're getting a `NoSuchElementException`.

You do this via `Scanner`'s `has*` methods.

For example:

```
    ArrayList<String> List = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner write = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (write.hasNextLine()) {
        String ListInList = write.nextLine();
        if (ListInList.equals("enter")) break;
        List.add(ListInList);
    }
    // No need to remove the last item from the list.
```

---

But also, I notice that you have a loop in your `main` method, where you call `Pages()` in that loop. If you close `write`, you also close `System.in`; once a stream is closed, you can't re-open it. So if you try to read things from `System.in` the next time you call `Pages()`, the stream is already closed, so there's nothing to read.

Simply don't call `write.close()`. You shouldn't close streams that you didn't open in general; and you didn't open `System.in` (the JVM did when it started up), so don't close it.

Comment: I don't get it. Wouldn't the Scanner effectively keep reading off of stdin as long as "enter" is not put in? Why the hasNext() and when will it be false?

Comment: `hasNext()` will return false if the scanner does not have another token. This can happen, for example, if the stream is closed.

Comment: @MoeA no, because that will result in `System.in` being closed afterwards.

Comment: ...because you call that method in a loop. As I explain in the second half of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using a while loop like this:

```
while (write.hasNextLine()) {
  ListInList = write.nextLine();
  if (doneWriting(ListInList)) { // Check for use of enter.
    break; // Exit the while loop when enter is found.
  }
  List.add(ListInList); // No enter found. Add input to diary entry.
}
```

where `doneWriting()` is a method (that you write!) which checks to see if the user has typed `enter`.

[Here is the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) for the `next()` method of Scanner. If you read it, you will see that it throws the exception you are getting when it runs out of tokens.

If you want a little bit more a casual explanation [here is a question that was asked previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class) about `next()` versus `nextLine()`.