# java program is not able to read a string

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

class DataTypes {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i = 4;
        double d= 4.0;
        String s = "Hackerrank";
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int j = scan.nextInt();
        double d1 = scan.nextDouble();
        String s1 = new String();
        s1 = scan.nextLine();
        j = j+i;
        System.out.println(j);
        d1 = d1+d;
        System.out.println(d1);
        System.out.println(s+" "+s1);
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

See the above code it is error free but after I input the double the program does not read the string it directly shows the output. But When I comment the scanning statements of int and double then the programs reads my string. Why is it so?

Comment: Why do you use a `Scanner` if your value is already set?

Comment: @foxdie value is already set to s not to s1. I want to print concatenated string of s and s1 by reading s1 from user.

Comment: He's talking about "new String()".

Comment: @Andy.inamdar The `Scanner` allows you to input values ​​in the console ...it serves you to verify that your result is correct or that a variable has good values. This is not a GUI that you can format... This is more an information.

Answer (score 7):

You are not reading the string as you want, just use below code to make it work as you want

```
s1 = scan.next();
```

For more information please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class)

**EDIT :**
If your input consist a string with spaces than you can do something like:

```
scan.nextLine();
s1 = scan.nextLine();
```

This is because of `nextDouble()`, this method does not consume the last newline character of your input, and thus that newline is consumed in the next call to `nextLine()`. Adding `newLine()` before reading String will consume the new Line and you will be able to input your String.

Comment: What if the input is "This is nextLine"?

Comment: Yes. It's obvious. But the OP asks for scanning new "line", not first word.

Comment: Better. Also, if you explain why "new String()" shouldn't be used, your answer will be complete.

Comment: The provided link says nothing about what I mentioned. See the line "String s1 = new String();" in the question.

Comment: @LalitVerma Thanks a lot. Its working. But why is it working now? why we need to use scan.nextLine() before s1 = scan.nextLine()? May I know the reason please? It will be helpful for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
s1 = scan.nextLine();
```

to

```
s1 = scan.next();
```

Comment: but it does not take the space within strings

Comment: try this `double d1 = Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine());`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import java.util.*;
class Demo{
public static void main(String args[]){
  int i = 4;
  double d= 4.0;
  String s = "Hackerrank";
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  int j = scan.nextInt();
  double d1 = scan.nextDouble();
  String s1  = scan.next();
  j = j+i;
  System.out.println(j);
  d1 = d1+d;
  System.out.println(d1);
  System.out.println(s+" "+s1);
  scan.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code as it is hardly readable. You could also put some description instead of ready to use solution

Answer (score 0):

Changing the line

```
 s1 = scan.nextLine();
```

to below line

```
 s1 = scan.next();
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

this is because of you enters: , so till get new line it can not go to next line
so for non string use example:

> int j = scan.nextInt(); scan.nextLine();

```
import java.util.*;

class DataTypes {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int i = 4;
        double d = 4.0;
        String s = "Hackerrank";
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

//      System.out.print("Enter j: ");
        int j = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
//      System.out.print("Enter dl: ");
        double d1 = scan.nextDouble();
        scan.nextLine();

        String s1 = new String();
//      System.out.print("Enter s1: ");
        s1 = scan.nextLine();
        j = j + i;
        System.out.println(j);
        d1 = d1 + d;
        System.out.println(d1);
        System.out.println(s + " " + s1);
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this lines as

```
double d1 = Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is appearing because a call to `nextDouble` only consumes the number itself, and not only newlines after it.

This happens:

1. Your program asks the scanner for a new double
2. Your give the console 4 characters: `0.1\n`
3. Scanner reads from the console, and gets `0.1\n`
4. Since it now can calculate where the double ends, it pushes back `\n` to its buffer
5. Your program asks the scanner for a new newline
6. The scanner reads from its buffers: `\n`
7. Since it found a valid line ending, it returns the string in front of it without the trailing newline.

There are different solutions for this:

**Prepend the string directly after the number in the input:**

```
1 3.5I'm a short string
```

**Consume the unneeded line character in your code manually:**

```
        double d1 = scan.nextDouble();
        scan.nextLine();
        String s1 = scan.nextLine();
```

**Call next instead of nextLine:**

Notice, this will only consume 1 word at a time

```
        double d1 = scan.nextDouble();
        String s1 = scan.next();
```

**Read the double using a call to nextline:**

This will limit your program to newline separated numbers, instead of allowing any seperator:

```
int j = Integer.parseInteger(scan.nextLine());
double d1 = Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine());
String s1 =scan.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

> It happens because after inputing the double value you press the enter key and it scans the "enter key" value which is considered to be new line for that reason it is showing you the output as soon as you hit enter.

> Instead what you can do is read the enter key and ignore and then read the next line like this.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 4;
        double d= 4.0;
        String s = "Hackerrank";
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int j = scan.nextInt();
        double d1 = scan.nextDouble();
        String s1 = new String();
        scan.nextLine(); // add this to read enter key 
        s1 = scan.nextLine();
        j = j+i;
        System.out.println(j);
        d1 = d1+d;
        System.out.println(d1);
        System.out.println(s+" "+s1);
        scan.close();
    }
}
```