# ReverseString program

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a `ReverseString` program. It's only returning **one word** only. I would like a **full sentence**.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word = input.next();

        String reverse = "";
        for (int i = word.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            reverse += word.charAt(i);

        System.out.println(reverse);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class

Comment: Try `String sentence = input.nextLine();`, and reverse that .

Comment: `input.nextLine()`

Comment: Awesome. Got it! thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between next() and nextLine() methods from Scanner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class)

Comment: and also you could use something like `new StringBuilder("some_string").reverse().toString()` instead of loop and other stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `reverse` method of the StringBuilder/StringBuffer class.
Something like :

`String reversedString = new StringBuilder(input.nextLine()).reverse().toString();`

Or if you want a more low-level approach you could use a `Stack` push every character in it and pop it one by one to get the reversal of it.

```
public String reverseString(String s) {
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        stack.push(s.charAt(i));
    }
    while (!stack.empty()) {
        stringBuilder.append(stack.pop());
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: While this solves the issue, I think OP searched for an explanation why his approach doesn't work, i.e. debugging help.

Comment: I see i didn't quite catch that. Well he can use this to make it work :D