# Repeating the program for the user

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java, I have written a simple input java program. I am giving the user the option to repeat the program with a do while, however it's not properly functioning. Can someone point my mistake please?

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    char repeat = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    do{ 
        String word = null;
        boolean oneWord = false;
        while(!oneWord){
            System.out.println("Please enter a word: ");
            try{
                word = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();
                word= word.trim();
                int words = word.isEmpty() ? 0 : word.split("\\s+").length;
                if(words==1 && word.length()>1 && word.length()<100){
                    System.out.println("Success");
                    oneWord = true;
                    System.out.println("Continue(Y/N)");
                    repeat = input.next().charAt(0);
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Failure.");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception occurred");
            }
        }
    }while(repeat=='Y'|| repeat=='y');
    input.close();
}
```

Comment: what is not functioning properly?

Comment: Could you describe what you are expecting from it? Then we will be able to help you.

Comment: When I input y, the output is:
Please enter a word: 
Failure.
Please enter a word:

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic).
From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even tho its a duplicate, have a look at the line

```
repeat = input.next().charAt(0);
```

and change it to

```
repeat = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

This will solve your problem. For further information regarding the problem, read the [duplicate link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you using nextLine() function of Scanner class instead of next() function.

[See the difference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class)