# Using split() method in a two dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to take input as a single line with spaces then enter that data into the two dimensional array.

```
String[][] examples = new String[100][100];
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    System.out.println("enter line " + i);
    String line = sc.next();
    String[] linearr = line.split("\\s+");
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        examples[i][j] = linearr[j];
        System.out.println(linearr[j]);
    }
}
```

Only the `linearr[0]` gets value entered `...linearr[1] , linearr[2]` , so on do not get values rather says index out of bounds.

Comment: Try `String line=sc.nextLine();` .

Comment: By far the best way to know what's wrong with this code is to use the powerful debugger built into your IDE to step through the code statement by statement, inspecting the contents of variables, etc. Using a debugger is **not** an advanced skill. It's one of the first things any beginner should learn, soon after their first "hello world" program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sc.next()` only returns the first word.

`sc.nextLine()` returns the whole line.

And instead of

```
for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
{
    examples[i][j]=linearr[j];
    System.out.println(linearr[j]);
}
```

you can just do

```
examples[i] = linearr;
```

Comment: In which case you can initialize `new String[100][]`.

Answer (score 1):

You wanted to receive a line, but your current code only receive a word per input.

Instead of using:

```
String line=sc.next();        //receive a word
```

Change it to:

```
String line=sc.nextLine();    //receive a line
```

> so on dont get values rather says index out of bounds.....

Instead of using `5`, the number of String tokens from the split can be used as the loop control for your inner loop, so you may want:

```
for(int j=0; j < linearr.length; j++)
```

This will prevent `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when there are lesser than 5 words in the input.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `sc.next()`:

```
 String line=sc.next();
```

You should use:

```
String line=sc.nextLine();
```

> Because next() can read input only till space and should be used for only single word.And if you are about to read a line you should use nextLine()

To know more [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class)