# Trying to split string based on commas without receiving an error on spaces

Tags: java, split

Code:

```
public static void createMovie() {
        String fileName = "C:\\Users\\kat7r\\eclipse-workspace\\Final OOPs project\\src\\movielist.txt";
        File movieFile = new File(fileName);
        try {

            Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(movieFile);
            inputStream.next();
            while (inputStream.hasNext()) {
                String movieArgs = inputStream.next();
                String[] splitData = movieArgs.split(",");
                System.out.println(movieArgs);
                //int priority = Integer.parseInt(splitData[0]);
                //System.out.println("Priority: "+priority);
            }

        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
```

**Expected output:**

Priority,Name,Genre,Length,Rating

1,Inception,Science Fiction,2.47,8

2,Shawshank Redemption,Drama,2.37,9

3,Coco,Fantasy,1.82,8

4,Lord of the rings,Fantasy,3.8,9

5,Thor: Ragnarok,Fantasy,2.17,8

**Actual output;**

1,Inception,Science

Fiction,2.47,8

2,Shawshank

Redemption,Drama,2.37,9

3,Coco,Fantasy,1.82,8

4,Lord

of

the

rings,Fantasy,3.8,9

5,Thor:

Ragnarok,Fantasy,2.17,8

**Comments:**

Essentially the spaces are causing the IDE to start a new line. I tried using `.nextLine` but that didn't help. Tried going online as well.

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: read about Scanner.useDelimiter()

Comment: `next()` uses space as a default delimiter. You need to use `nextLine()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you use  :

```
inputStream.nextLine();
while(inputStream.hasNextLine())
{
   String movieArgs = inputStream.nextLine(); 
   String[] splitData = movieArgs.split(",");
   System.out.println(movieArgs);
}
```

Comment: Initially I had used an excel file that I had saved to .csv format and I tried .nextLine but it didn't work. Since then I've switched to a .txt file format and used your suggestion which made the code work. I know this isn't part of the initial question but is there a way to do it with a .csv file?

Comment: @astral004 
I've never actually heard of a .csv file before but seeing as it's actually a .txt file in the bg (with a very rigid structure), I don't see why it wouldn't work.

The same algo should work in either case.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to read the whole line of the input, use `inputStream.nextLine()` instead of `inputStream.next()`. Refer to this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

It works for me:

```
public static void createMovie() {
    String fileName = "C:\\Movies.txt";
    File movieFile = new File(fileName);
    try {
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(movieFile);
        while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
            String movieArgs = inputStream.nextLine();
            System.out.println(movieArgs);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```