# Capturing first word and assigning a variable

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    // Create a usable instance of an input device
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Prompt user for input
    System.out.println("Please enter you first name:");
    // Capture first word and assign it to A Variable
    String firstName;
    firstName = sc.next();
    //Construct the greeting
    System.out.println("Hello, " + sc.next() + "!");
```

I am able to output the name on the screen but I have to type it in twice. I believe it is due to the sc.next statement but I am not for certain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is due to the `sc.next()` because you are doing it twice. 
Change your last line to

```
System.out.println("Hello, " + firstName + "!");
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
System.out.println("Hello, " + firstName + "!");
```

after first sc.next() it's empty (also look nextLine)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you call `sc.next()` twice:

```
    firstName = sc.next(); // 1st time
    //Construct the greeting
    System.out.println("Hello, " + sc.next() + "!"); //2nd time
```

Please use the assigned variable `firstname`instead:

```
    firstName = sc.next();
    //Construct the greeting
    System.out.println("Hello, " + firstName + "!");
```

This should fix you issue.

Answer (score 0):

System asks you to enter 'first name' for 2 times because you calling **sc.next()** for two times.
To prevent this you can do it this way:

```
...
//Construct the greeting
System.out.println("Hello, " + firstName + "!");
...
```

or even this way, if you will not use `String firstName` in the future:

```
...
System.out.println("Please enter you first name:");
//Construct the greeting
System.out.println("Hello, " + sc.next() + "!");
...
```

I will also prefer to use `nextLint()` instead of `next()` because it automatically moves the scanner down after returning the current line.
If you interested you can take a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22458766/8913124