# Splitting a Scanner Input Into Strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, java.util.scanner

I've been looking for an answer to this for a while, but for some reason, none of them seem to work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter full name (last, first)");
    String[] personalInfo = scanner.next().split(", ");
    String firstName = personalInfo[1];
    String lastName = personalInfo[0];

    System.out.println("Your info: " +  firstName + " " + lastName);
```

There is my code. I'm basically trying to obtain the personal info, which would be the first and last name. I want to split the first and last name into 2 different strings, but whenever I try to print this, I get the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1  > out of bounds for length 1
>   at Fines.main(Fines.java:11)

I'm confused because I even started the array with 0 like I was supposed to.. I just don't understand what is going incorrectly.

Please give me a hand - thanks in advance!

Comment: Read the javadoc of Scanner. What does .next() do? What is a "token"? Is there any other method which would fit better?

Answer (score 1):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   Index 1 > out of bounds for length 1 at Fines.main(Fines.java:11)

As the size of the `personalInfo` is `1` not `2`.

use `nextLine()` instead of `next()` because `next()` will only return the input that comes before a space.

`String[] personalInfo = scanner.next().split(", ");` should be

```
String[] personalInfo = scanner.nextLine().split(", ");
```

You might want to read this [What's the difference between next() and nextLine() methods from Scanner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is scanner.nextLine() to read from standard input up until end of line. Then split would work as you expected.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter full name (last, first)");
String[] personalInfo = scanner.nextLine().split(", ");
String firstName = personalInfo[1];
String lastName = personalInfo[0];

System.out.println("Your info: " +  firstName + " " + lastName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    System.out.println("Please enter full name (last, first)");
    String firstName = scan.next();
    String lastName = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Your info: " + firstName + ' ' + lastName);
}
```

`scanner.next()` read until next delimiter (space by default), so it ready only the `firstName`. Just replace it with `scanner.nextLine()` or use `scanner.next()` two times.