# How do i check if my array contains a word that has spaces in it?

Tags: java, arrays

```
int num;
num = in.nextInt();
String array[] = new String[num];
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    array[i] = in.next();
    if (array[i].equals("hey guys"))
        System.out.println("hey guys");
    else
        System.out.println("buzz");
}
```

This is the code i tried. When i remove the space in "hey guys", it works allright but otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: [Read it carefully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class) you should use nextLine() method.

Answer (score 1):

Just use in.nextLine() instead of in.next().
It will take line input including spaces.

```
int num;
num = in.nextInt();
String array[] = new String[num];
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    array[i] = in.nextLine();
    if (array[i].equals("hey guys"))
        System.out.println("hey guys");
    else
        System.out.println("buzz");
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah how did i miss that? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use contains() method from String class to check if the string has spaces in it.But from what I understood,you are facing the issue while reading the string with spaces.You should read in using in.nextLine()

```
int num;
num=in.nextInt();
String array[]=new String[num];
for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
array[i]=in.nextLine();
if(array[i].contains(" "))
//contains space
else 
System.out.println("buzz");}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful!