# Why i am not able to use nextLine() in place of next()?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Below is the java program:-

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program{
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean state=true;
    while(state){
        System.out.println("Welcome");
        System.out.println("Press 1 to enter your name ");
        System.out.println("Press 2 to exit");
        int input =sc.nextInt();
        switch(input){
            case 1:{
                System.out.print("Enter your name : ");
                String name=sc.nextLine();
                //String name=sc.next();
                System.out.println("Your name is\""+name+"\" and it is a beautiful name.");
            }
            break;
            case 2:{
                System.out.println("Goodbye");
                state=false;
            }
            break;
            default:{
                System.out.println("Wrong input");
            }
        }
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

}

I ran this program and when i entered 1 as input i was unable to enter value of name variable and it printed on its own and then continued the execution but when i used next() in place of nextLine() the program worked properly.
Why i am not able to use nextLine() here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between next() and nextLine() methods from Scanner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class)

Answer (score 0):

`next()` places the cursor in the same line after reading the input. `nextLine()` reads input including space between the words

Comment: I know that but why i am not able to use nextLine() here?

Comment: @smaltamash Have you read the two links in the comments under your question?

Comment: I just read them, they were very useful and got my confusion cleared
thankyou @Ivar