# next() vs nextLIne() in Scanner class

Tags: java

I am reading a number, then a string and then comparing the string.
This works fine:

```
    int num = sc.nextInt();
    String S = sc.next();
    if (S.equals("TEST")){
    //do something
    }
```

On giving i/p say 5 TEST, the program enters the if part.

But if I use .nextLine() instead, ie,

```
    int num = sc.nextInt();
    String S = sc.nextLine();
    if (S.equals("TEST")){
    //do something
    }
```

It doesn't work. For the same input(5 TEST) it won't execute the if part.

I know .next() reads up till the first whitespace and .nextLine() reads up till it encounters "\n". Here both of them are returning the same string, so what's going wrong here?

EDIT: Found out that .nextLine() was reading the String alongwith the preceding whitespace. Why? Does the .nextInt() function return the cursor to the point before it encounters the delimiter?

Comment: Have you tried printing out `S` to see what the value actually is?

Comment: @DanW yes, .nextLine() gives " S" (alongwith the preceding whitespace)

Comment: Possibly related: [What's the difference between next() and nextLine() methods from Scanner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22458575)

Comment: In short, `next()` returns next *token* without *delimiters* which by default is one-or-more-whitespaces (`\\s+`) while `nextLine()` doesn't care about delimiters set up for scanner, it sees as delimiter only line separator, so whitespace before `_TEST`  is non-delimiter for it, so it is included as part of result.

Comment: The question in your 'edit' is answered by reading the javadoc for Scanner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: @Progman That is not what this question is about. Here `nextLine()` doesn't hold empty value but `(space)TEST` which is causing `(S.equals("TEST")` to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Is simple: 
`next()`  return the next token using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace (so white space are eliminated because are separator) instead `nextLine()` read from the current cursor position to the end of the line.