# why is it giving me an java.util.InputMismatchException when i run this code when I use a text file with the text (shown underneath)

Tags: java, inputmismatchexception

```
import java.util.*;

public void readToolData(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    File dataFile = new File(fileName);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(dataFile);
    scanner.useDelimiter(",");

    while( scanner.hasNext() )
    {
        String toolName = scanner.next();
        String itemCode = scanner.next();
        int timesBorrowed = scanner.nextInt();
        boolean onLoan = scanner.nextBoolean();
        int cost = scanner.nextInt();
        int weight = scanner.nextInt();
        storeTool(new Tool(toolName, itemCode, timesBorrowed, onLoan, cost, weight));
    }

    scanner.close();
}
```

File:

```
Makita BHP452RFWX,RD2001, 12 ,false,14995,1800
Flex Impact Screwdriver FIS439,RD2834,14,true,13499,1200
DeWalt D23650-GB Circular Saw, RD6582,54,true,14997,5400
Milwaukee DD2-160XE Diamond Core Drill,RD4734,50,false,38894,9000
Bosch GSR10.8-Li Drill Driver,RD3021,25, true,9995,820
Bosch GSB19-2REA Percussion Drill,RD8654,85,false,19999,4567
Flex Impact Screwdriver FIS439, RD2835,14,false,13499,1200
DeWalt DW936 Circular Saw,RD4352,18,false,19999,3300
Sparky FK652 Wall Chaser,RD7625,15,false,29994,8400
```

Comment: ,could you try using scanner.nextLine instead od scanner.next() , as I can see in your toolName there is space . Please refer this for difference between next and nextLine . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the delimiter to include optional spaces around commas, and the new line characters as well. Something like this:

```
scanner.useDelimiter("(\\s*,\\s*)|(\r\n)|(\n)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the InputMismatchException in `int timesBorrowed = scanner.nextInt()` for the first line of the input file. The error is caused by the spaces around the comma.

Change the delimiter to `*, *` then any number of spaces around the comma become part of the delimiter and thus get removed. Instead of the spaces you may also use `\\s` which covers all whitespaces (space and tabs).

Then you get the exception in line `int weight = scanner.nextInt()` again for the first line of the input file, because the `1800` is followed by a line break. So what you need is a delimiter which also matches the line breaks: `( *, *)|[\r\n]+`

The regular expression means: Either a comma surrounded by any number of spaces or at least one consecutive line break. Note that Unix files have usually only `\n` while Windows file have usually both characters `\r\n` in each line break. So that expression covers both file formats and also skips empty lines.

Here is a full example which works:

```
public class Main
{

    public static void readToolData(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        File dataFile = new File(fileName);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(dataFile);
        scanner.useDelimiter("( *, *)|[\r\n]+");
        while (scanner.hasNext())
        {
            String toolName = scanner.next();
            String itemCode = scanner.next();
            int timesBorrowed = scanner.nextInt();
            boolean onLoan = scanner.nextBoolean();
            int cost = scanner.nextInt();
            int weight = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println("toolName=" + toolName + ", weight=" + weight);
        }
        scanner.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        readToolData("/home/stefan/Programmierung/PC-Java/test/src/test.txt");
    }
}
```

Comment: using this code I still get inputMismatchException. I used `scanner.useDelimiter("( *, *)|(\\s*,\\s*)|(\r\n)|(\n)");` also note: I am not allowed to change anything in the text file.

Comment: It seems that you have also trailing whitespaces at the end of some lines, which need to be included in the regular expresssion. You have already an example that shows the principle how it works. The rest (reading the docs and developing the regexp) is up to you. See also my other anser where I recommend to read line by line - there it is much easier to cover all possible issues.

Answer (score -1):

The issue here is that your lines are not ending with a comma and there are newlines.

This is what your program is interpreting the first two lines of your input as:

```
Makita BHP452RFWX,RD2001, 12 ,false,14995,1800\nFlex Impact Screwdriver FIS439,RD2834,14,true,13499,1200
```

Notice how there is no comma after 1800? There is a `\n` which denotes a newline.

Edit: I'm also noticing spaces after some commas, so that would likely be messing with things also. Try out Eng.Fouad's answer as it addresses my concerns.

Comment: But the error I am getting is on `int timesBorrowed = scanner.nextInt();`

Comment: Because there are spaces around the ```12```.

Answer (score -1):

If you read the file line by line you can add additional checks, e.g. filter out comments (lines starting with "//" in this case):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{

    public static void readToolData(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        File dataFile = new File(fileName);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(dataFile);
        while (scanner.hasNext())
        {
            String line = scanner.nextLine().trim();
            if (line.isEmpty() || line.startsWith("//"))
            {
                // skip this line
                continue;
            }

            // Split the line
            String[] parts = line.split(" *, *");

            String toolName = parts[0];
            String itemCode = parts[1];
            int timesBorrowed = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
            boolean onLoan = Boolean.parseBoolean(parts[3]);
            int cost = Integer.parseInt(parts[4]);
            int weight = Integer.parseInt(parts[5]);

            System.out.println("toolName=" + toolName + ", weight=" + weight);
        }
        scanner.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        readToolData("/home/stefan/Programmierung/PC-Java/test/src/test.txt");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you give two answers?

Comment: Because azzy asked for it in another thread about the same topic which had been closed wrongly as a "duplicate question".