# Loop expects an input, while it should've iterated through every word of previous input

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

Need to change every word, that starts with vowel to the longest one. Everything seems ok, however have faced with an unexpected behaviour from the loop, when I enter into it - scanner wants an input (7th line). Instead of asking for an input, it should iterate through every element (word) from the sentence I've set previously (2nd line). I do assume, that I've missed something.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String textToFormat = sc.nextLine();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(textToFormat);

    while (sc.hasNext()) {
      currentWord = sc.next();
      if (currentWord.length() > longestWord.length()) {
        longestWord = currentWord;

      } else break;
    }
```

Comment: so what is the sc.hasNext and sc.next for? Just call the split method on the textToFormat String

Comment: related: [What's the difference between next() and nextLine() methods from Scanner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class)

Comment: @jhamon how is that related? he shouldn't be calling hasNext, nor the next() method

Comment: @Stultuske Read your own comment to know how it's related. Then check the linked answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your code, I see you are trying to find the longest string in a sentence inputted by user.
There is no need to input every word individually when you simply could input the entire line. Something like the following code could help you:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static String findLongestWord(String[] arr){
        String longest = "";
        for (String current : arr){
            // If the current word is larger than the longest.
            if(current.length() > longest.length()){
                longest = current; // Then set longest word to current.
            }
        }
        return longest;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Get the sentence from the user.
        System.out.println("Input a sentence: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        // Split sentence into words.
        String[] arr = s.split("\\W+");
        System.out.println("Longest word is " + findLongestWord(arr));
    }
}
```

When run with input `Find the longest word in this large sentence` this outputs:

```
Input a sentence: 
Find the longest word in this large sentence.
Longest word is sentence
```

Comment: Never thought of splitting sc.nextLine() into an array of Strings. Works just fine. Still trying to realize why did I choose that while loop for iterating, guess need to refresh my knowledge about it. Thanks

Comment: @her0ftheday  Thank you for the upvote and accept. PS: If you don't use `nextLine()` you basically input a word one-by-one which is something not inherently wrong but still tedious.