# How to write a string made up of two or more words?

Tags: java, string

I have a method that helps to enter information about movies, then write them in the file.

Writing a name (eg The Shawshank Redemption) in the file only writes "The".

What can I do in this case?

```
System.out.print("Name movie:");
String name=input.next();
input.nextLine();
System.out.print("Genre:");
String genre=input.next();
input.nextLine();
System.out.print("Country:");
String country=input.next();
Movie movie = new Movie(name, genre, country);
input.nextLine();
write(movie);
```

Method write()

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Movie.txt", true); 
fw.write(i.name+" "+i.genre+" "+i.country+"\n");
fw.close();
```

Word is read to space, and in the .txt file only the first word to space is written

Comment: Debug buddy. Is the name , genre and country has been read properly? that eliminates the scanner issue. Are you sure if the issue is while writing?

Comment: It seems like input.next() reads just the input till space, and that is the reason you miss the 'whole' move name.

Comment: are you sure you are setting correctly the name,genre and country? looks like you have an issue with that and the spaces... update the question please

Comment: See this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class

Comment: If you formatted your code along rational and accepted lines you would be better able to understand its workings for yourself, as would we.

Comment: Also note: separate concerns. WRITING data to a file is INDEPENDENT to where that data is coming from. Meaning: first focus on writing the code that reads user input. Just print that input, to see if it matches your expectation. Then, when that part works, write a second program that takes *predefined, hardcoded* data, and writes that to a file. And only when that part works, too ... then bring your code together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are scanning the inputs wrong. Here is an example:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Name movie:"); 
String name=input.nextLine();
System.out.print("Genre:"); 
String genre=input.nextLine();
System.out.print("Country:"); 
String country=input.nextLine();
System.out.println(name + " " + genre + " " + country);
```

Output:

```
Name movie:new movie
Genre:this genre
Country:that country
new movie this genre that country
```

In this way, you scan the whole line at each input instead of scanning the first word and jumping to an empty line after that.

Comment: This is why debugging, even by copious print statements, is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
String name=input.next();input.nextLine();
```

with

```
String name=input.nextLine();
```

The problem with your current approach is that `input.next()` is scanning only the first word and storing it into `name`. The change will scan the complete line (i.e. the full name of the movie) instead of stopping the scan after the first word.