# Can't get program to break on specific string

Tags: java

The code works for the most part, but if I type "No way" it still stops the loop. Should I set it up a different way or use a length function ? Everything I've searched on breaking a loop used integers.

See the code below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CarryOn {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Shall we carry on?");
            String answer = String.valueOf(scanner.next());
            
            if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be preferable if you were to begin explaining how your code is suppose to work. Instead of letting users try to deduce it from reading your code.

Comment: Understood and makes sense. Ty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.next` in this case only stores "no" in "no way". Use `.nextLine` instead:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
     System.out.println("Shall we carry on?");
     String answer = String.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
     if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
          break;
     }
}
```

Output:

```
Shall we carry on?
no way
Shall we carry on?
no
```

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

```
scanner.next()
```

only reads a single token. `No way` is two tokens: `No` and `way`.

Use `scanner.nextLine()` instead, if you want to read the whole line.