# difference between next() and nextLine() in java

Tags: java

I used the current code to check the difference between `nextLine()` and `next()`

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Add a String\n");
String string1 = sc.next(); 
System.out.println(string1);
String string2=sc.nextLine();
System.out.println(string2);
```

when I was executing the program, it displayed "Add a string" for the first entry and I was able to enter the first string, but I was not able to enter the second string.

I want to know why and how to fix that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between next() and nextLine() methods from Scanner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class)

Answer (score 0):

From the [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) documentation:

> `String nextLine(): Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped.`
>
> `String next(): Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.`

Answer (score 0):

```
sc.nextLine()
```

will block until you enter a line seperator (= hit the enter-button) and then return everything entered excluding the line seperator

see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()

Answer (score 0):

As per javadocs:

`next()` - Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern.

All **whitespace** characters are considered as delimiters, so the string: `"i add a string"` **for multiple calls** on `sc.next()` will be split into: `"i"`, `"add"`, `"a"`, `"string"`.

`nextLine()` - Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the **rest of the current line**, excluding any line separator at the end.

`sc.nextLine()` will return the whole string up to the end of the current line. But, not the **rest** part, this means that if a previous call on `sc` read a couple of characters, **it will continue from there up to the end of the line**.

So, for the string: `"i add a string"`, `next()` reads `"i"`, `nextLine()` reads `"add a string"`. (`"i"` was read from `next()`)

More info here:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--