# Why is my method printing null instead of the array?

Tags: java

What could be wrong in this code? The test system of the exercise throws the following error

> call to the getIntegers () method printed a value of" null ", but" [1,2,3,4,5, 6] "expected. Tip: Check your spaces and / or spelling.

Could it be the `private static scanner scanner = new scanner (System.in);` since I use it in the main but the system does not allow adding the main, since it brings it by default?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class formato {
    

    public static int[] getIntegers(int capacity) {
        static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] array = new int[capacity];
        System.out.println("Enter "+capacity+" integer values:\r");
        for(int i = 0; i<array.length ; i++){
        array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        return array;
    
    }

    public static void printArray(int[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Element " + i + " contents " + array[i]);
        }
    }

    public static int[] sortIntegers(int[] array) {
        // int[] sortedArray = new int[array.length];
        // for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        // sortedArray[i] = array[i];
        int[] sortedArray = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
        // }
        boolean flag = true;
        int temp;
        while (flag) {
            flag = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < sortedArray.length - 1; i++) {
                if (sortedArray[i] < sortedArray[i + 1]) {
                    temp = sortedArray[i];
                    sortedArray[i] = sortedArray[i + 1];
                    sortedArray[i + 1] = temp;
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return sortedArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you write `private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);` right after `public class formato`, outside the main?

Comment: Did your code compile? I mean, ```static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);``` inside of a method...? At least it did not compile on mine...

Comment: yeah as @Frightera  said ..add it in class as member  'private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);' it should compile then refer scanner in your static function.. remove 'scanner' from getIntegers

Comment: I meant `public class formato { private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in) ... ` @lierwu Not inside any of the methods.

Comment: @Frightera No... I'm not talking to you(That sounds mean...) I'm saying OP had ```public static int[] getIntegers(int capacity) {static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);.....}```where the scanner is inside a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a class constant:

`public static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);`

This will help you.

or else just use `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);`

Answer (score 0):

So the place where this error has occurred gives input as "1 2 3 4 5 6" (on checking user logs, input is given as "1 2 3 4 5 6" & not [1,2,3,4,5,6]), so the part where error has arose is "sc.nextLine()" or "sc.nextInt()" being used. The problem is resolved if "sc.next()" is used.

For explanation of difference between next & nextLine/nextInt of scanner, you could view [What's the difference between next() and nextLine() methods from Scanner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class)