# Whitespace split issue, java

Tags: java

beginner here I have searched anywhere but I can't seem to find any solution or problems related to mine. I've just started learning java and Here is my problem:

I have a working code where the input is split by "/":

```
Scanner d = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your birthday (mm/dd/yyyy): ");
String birthday = d.next();

String[] bdayArr = birthday.split("/", 3);

int current = 2022;
int age = current - Integer.parseInt(bdayArr[2]);
```

now it was just a solution for the meantime as the date format I want to needs to be seperated with spaces (ex, January 21, 1899)
and the purpose of me splitting is i need to get the year to use in a code block that computes the age of the person based on the birth year.

However, when i try to split it by whitespace I can't seem to access the array anymore. Error codes ranging from out of bounds to a NumberFormatException when i input (ex: January 21, 1989) (code below)

`String[] bdayArr = birthday.split("\\s+", 3);`

I don't know what i'm doing wrong, hopefully someone can help. (I know the question is too long and not straight to the point I wanted to provide as much context)

Comment: If you split `"January 21, 1989"` by whitespaces you'll end up with `"January"`, `"21,"` and `"1989"`. Does your code handle that dangling comma after the 21?

Comment: I haven't come across exception handling(? sorry really still new to this thing), so in short nope. :< however one thing i may add is even if i input 21 and 1989 it says it is out of bounds for some reason (Index 2 out of bounds for length 1) so im guessing it's not reading the array at all? or it didn't split in the first place?

Comment: Note that in an actual java app you shouldn't be doing any of this. You parse dates using a date parser, such as `DateTimeFormatter`. Don't let that distract you though - you're learning, "not production quality" is kinda the point :) – just be aware that if there's a voice in your head saying: "Huh, this all seems thoroughly complicated and unwieldy, surely there is a much better way to do all this" - yeah, there is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by `d.next()`, you should use `d.nextLine()` insted.
to understand why you should check this quesiton [What's the difference between next() and nextLine() methods from Scanner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458575/whats-the-difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-from-scanner-class)

Comment: Thank you for this one! However, one more thing this may sound as a very stupid question but is it okay to use `nextLine` for everything input related? From int inputs to Doubles, or should there be integers or doubles I should use the appropriate ones?

Comment: I would go with the second option

Comment: @WazuWazu the advice 'only use `nextLine()`' is common, but incorrect. The correct way to use scanner when dealing with keyboard input is to set the delimiter to the enter key: `scanner.useDelimiter("\\R")`. Now, use all `next()` methods, __except__ `nextLine()`, don't use that at all. __ALL__ the `nextX()` methods now read an entire line. Use the next method that matches the input you need. Want an int? `.nextInt()`. Want someone's name? `.next()`.